# session share between different war modules possible in jboss?

Tags: grails, jboss

Is there an easy way to share session between different war modules in jboss?

I have a Grails app running in jboss, but want to create a new Grails war module which looks & feels the same as the existing one (but, don't want user to login again). The domain will be same, for example, if I have war1 and war2, the domain should be

http://domain.com/war1 <-- login should be done here..
http://domain.com/war2

I searched through the web, but couldn't find an easy/or difficult way to do this.
Please help~.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No HTTP sessions are not shareable between servlets from different apps. What you really need is a Single Sign On solution.  A poor man's SSO can be built with cookies but I wouldn't call it a very secure way.  First session can set a cookie and the second session can read the same cookie - this will work as long as the domains are the same for both apps.

Good luck!

Comment: How do you plan to implement SSO without cookie?

Comment: You are right, what I should have said was an encrypted cookie (ala SiteMinder). however there are other ways I suppose too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832057/single-sign-on-without-cookies-in-java

Comment: :That is URL Rewriting. Cookie is better compared to that, I guess. So you meant cookies sent during https?